# Update text column, add/remove text at character index

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I update a text column, adding and/or removing text in the middle of the string?

Examples

- Add "abc" to "0123456" at index 3, to make "012abc3456"
- Remove index 3 to index 5 of "0123456", to make "0126"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `overlay` for the first:

```
select overlay('0123456' placing 'abc' from 4 for 0)
```

And for the second as well:

```
select overlay('0123456' placing '' from 4 for 3)
```